# How do I display Year on year growth in an expression in SSRS?

Tags: sql, excel, reporting-services

How do I display the following info in SSRS? 
The formula in the cell in Column H is "=IFERROR(F3/D3-1, 0)".

[image]

I don't know how it is done technically. But something like

((Revenue where Year = FY14  and Condition = Y)/(Revenue where Year = FY13 and Condition = U)) -1

Aim is to show the Year On Year growth. Thank you.

Comment: Give your textboxes descriptive names and do `ReportItem!TexboxF3.Value / ReportItem!TextBoxD3.Value - 1` (and add error checking)